# sum of two linearly independent eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

'' The sum of two linearly independent eigenvectors is never an eigenvector. ''

- This is true?
- if i assume the opposite, then it means the eigenvector can be written as a combination linear of the 2 other eigenvector (coefficient 1 of each), which won't make them linearly independent, which means they wouldn't be eigenvectors in the first place, is this correct?

Comment: Rolled back to the original because the edit mangled the question so it no longer made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity matrix, every single non-zero vector of compatible size is an eigenvector.

Hence the statement is false.